# Linking one HTML file to Another in Django 1.9

Tags: django

I am trying to learn Django 1.9. Basically trying to build a simple website with two pages. First page is a Home page that lets me fill first and last name with  "register" radio button. Once the register button is clicked, it should take me to a second  HTML file that confirms the registration.
I was finding a hard time reading Django documents trying to figure out how'';when I click the registration button would land me to the Second html page that reads "registration Confirmed".
A little bit of insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't have much to do with Django.  It's simple HTML.

Firstly, register should be a submit button inside your form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Register">
```

When you create a form (which your 'register' would be within), you simply add the 'action' to the form tag, which is the url to which you'll send your page.  Something like this:

```
<form method='post' **action='registered/'**>
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="id_firstname">First Name:</label>
<input id="id_firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
<label for="id_lastname">Last Name:</label>
<input id="id_lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

In your urlconf, you then create url for it:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.registered, name='registered'),
```

I'd suggest you do the Django tutorial (and move on to Django 1.10).  You'd have understood this already if you did the tutorial.  Django can create these forms for you by passing them on from a 'form' object to your template.  All that's well covered in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="URL LINK GOES HERE">register</a>
```

django is a backend, handles the request for certain endpoints. you should have the other endpoint set up in your urls configuration and return the other html template.